# PCB,DIY USB Mobile Phone Charger. Shield to GND?

Tags: usb-device

Little project using a step down converter that steps down 13v from a car battery to 5v 3A. I have added Decoupling capacitors and so on to the 5v line for filtering(Probably gone overkill) but im wondering if i should  connect the USB Shield to ground directly or connect it using a ferrite bead from Shield to ground?.Or maybe shield to gnd using resistor ?or does not even matter ?

Also as this is only a charger and not doing any data do i need to add ESD Suppressors ESD Protection ?  (USBLC6-2 TVS )

mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/USBLC6-2SC6/?qs=po45yt2pPpu%2FhNIlwQdTlg%3D%3D

Answer (score 2):

Typically the shield would be tied directly to ground, and there would be a ferrite on the 5V line.  A ferrite on the shield would filter out noise, and defeats the purpose of tying the shield to ground.

In my opinion you don't need ESD protection on the data lines since there is no data connection, however you should tie the data pins together as some devices won't draw power otherwise.

Comment: Thank-you. i was going to put a 600r 4A ferrite on the 5v line however that ferrite is quiet expensive and i believe they can get very hot under load? i will tie usb shield to ground though a ferrite bead then.. i have seen schematics online showing shield's to ground with a ferrite bead but not sure what value to use. i have some BL01RN1-A62 Murata 7AMP that should be ok to use ? as for the data pins i have special ic's that detect and send out the correct voltages on the data pins for fast charging. i was thinking on  connecting a tvs diode to 5v line but am not sure what value to use.

Comment: OK, but in case I wasn't clear, my suggestion was to not use the ferrite on the ground.  I don't think I've seen that suggested anywhere.  Can you send links to where you have seen it?  I have seen in some places a series cap with resistor, which would have the opposite effect as a series ferrite (i.e. high frequency would be shorted directly to ground but DC levels would be allowed to stay on the shield.  That may be useful if the two devices are different potentials, but the ground line would prevent that anyway.  So again my opinion is tie shield directly to ground.

Comment: As for the 600R ferrite, not sure exactly to which you are referring, but you should check the DC resistance to calculate the power loss, but the temperature rise will depend on the thermal coefficient, which is not typically stated on datasheets for ferrites.  Just make sure the current rating is above you expected current by a reasonable margin and you will be fine.  For the ESD protection, there a wide variety of diodes and diode arrays available, and many customized for 5V, which is more applicable at higher frequencies.

Comment: [The SN65220](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn75240.pdf) is what I've been using lately.

Comment: i did read somewhere that the usb shield connections to the shielding in the usb cable and can act as an antenna. but all other usb chargers iv taken apart all tie shield to gnd so i think like you say it will be the right thing to do. i have some usblc6 to hand. http://atmel.eefocus.com/module/forum/data/attachment/forum/201507/02/195950nm0iu7j7gjdjzk48.png do i have to put the D+ into the diode D+ and out the otherside of the diode OR can i simply connect the diodes D+ IN and D+ out to the usb D+ or do they have to go thought the diode ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last question.